# MGSplitViewController:Detail view layout issue in iOS6

Tags: ios, ipad, rotation, uisplitviewcontroller

I'using MGSplitViewController(replacement of UISplitViewController).I posted the same question in :https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController/issues/81.

However, i still would like to post again here, hoping anybody else could help me out of this

Question description:
For detail view, In iOS5, it's OK. In iOS6, it seems that it doesn't deal with rotation (see attached yellow part: it's the background color of detail view)

[image]

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Patch https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController/pull/73/files#r1829508 seems to fix the issue.